# Unable to connect to ldap from jenkins

Tags: authentication, jenkins, ldap

Getting following error while connecting ldap server from jenkins. I am able connect to ldap from system via ldapsearch. But with jenkins, I am getting the error. Please help me in resolving the issue.

```
Unable to connect to ldap://<ldap url>:389 : javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1]; remaining name ''
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1]; remaining name ''
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3128)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3034)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2841)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1333)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:231)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:139)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:137)
    at hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.doCheckServer(LDAPSecurityRealm.java:1059)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please add further details, like your anonymized(!) LDAP settings.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error message, it sounds like your LDAP server does not allow anonymous connections.

> In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection.

In the Jenkins configuration, you need to provide a user and password with which to connect to the LDAP server. The *Manager DN* and *Manager password* are configured in the Advanced LDAP configuration. As described in the help text:

> A DN typically looks like CN=MyUser,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com although the exact sequence of tokens depends on the LDAP server configuration.